# How do you test top-level await?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

Simple top-level await. and testing throwing ReferenceError: await is not defined

```js
    const { Select } = await import('shell/Select');

    render() {
      return <Select .../>
    }


    test('testing top-level await', () => {
      render(<Select data-testid="operator"
            name="operator"
            inputId="operator"
            options={options}/>);

      expect(screen.getByText(/operator/i)).toBe('operator');
    });
```